# How to generate a json file in python from nested array/dictionary/object

Tags: python, json

I need to generate a json file like:

```
{
  "age":100,
  "name":"mkyong.com",
  "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]
}
```

The data in this file should be populated from various places. What is the best way to do this in python? I can always write as a text file (character by character). But I was wondering if there is a cleaner way by which an array could be created and use some library methods to generate this json file. Please suggest a good solution

PS. I am new to python

Comment: Use the builtin [json library](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) on your object...

Comment: But my input is not a json string

Comment: What do you want then? You want the indentation? You want to load json data? For all those, use the builtin json library I wrote above

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`json.dumps()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for that. You can pass a dictionary to it and the function will encode it as json.

Example:

```
import json

# example dictionary that contains data like you want to have in json
dic={'age': 100, 'name': 'mkyong.com', 'messages': ['msg 1', 'msg 2', 'msg 3']}

# get json string from that dictionary
json=json.dumps(dic)
print json
```

Output:

```
{"age": 100, "name": "mkyong.com", "messages": ["msg 1", "msg 2", "msg 3"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out...

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump({
    "age":100,
    "name":"mkyong.com",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]
     }, outfile)
```